# Asp.net and ListView Control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am printing data using List View control. I used LinkButton in itemtemplate. I want that column name should not be printed.....................................................
What changes i have to make?

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="userid" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <AlternatingItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="catgLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("catg") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="useridLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userid") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="datetimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("datetime") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="catgTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("catg") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="useridLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userid") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="datetimeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("datetime") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            <table runat="server" style="">
                <tr>
                    <td>No data was returned.</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                    <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Clear" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="catgTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("catg") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="useridTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("userid") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="datetimeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("datetime") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="catgLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("catg") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="useridLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userid") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="datetimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("datetime") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table runat="server">
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server">
                        <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
                            <tr runat="server" style="">
                                <th runat="server">catg</th>
                                <th runat="server">userid</th>
                                <th runat="server">datetime</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server">
                    <td runat="server" style=""></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <SelectedItemTemplate>
            <tr style="">
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="catgLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("catg") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="useridLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("userid") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="datetimeLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("datetime") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </SelectedItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
```

Comment: NOTE: You should always post an answer in case you solve it by yourself, so that it is helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ListView's `HeaderStyle` property to `None`. It can take 3 values:

```
a. None
b. Nonclickable
c. Clickable
```

The below exact texts from MSDN is sufficient::

The HeaderStyle property allows you to specify whether the column headers are visible or, if they are visible, whether they will function as clickable buttons. If the HeaderStyle property is set to ColumnHeaderStyle.None, the column headers are not displayed.

Let us know if you also tried the same or if different method, please post it here so as to be helpful to others.